# Creating data string for REST request

Tags: php

normally when I do a REST request I do something like this

```
$data = <<<EOF
            <Staff>
              <Name>John Smith</Name>
            </Staff>
            <Staff>
              <Name>Jane Smith</Name>
            </Staff>
EOF;
```

And then I pass this data to the request

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

However, this time I need to do this dynamically.  So I am trying to build up the block like the above, but with dynamic data.  At the moment, I have something like this

```
foreach($users as $staffMember) {
    $data =  "<Staff>
                  <Name>$staffMember</Name>
              </Staff>";
}
```

But that will only produce the last result.  If I have many staff members, how can I build up the raw body which can be passed in my request?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `.=` operator which appends data to a variable.

```
$data = "";

foreach($users as $staffMember) {
    $data .=  "<Staff>
                  <Name>$staffMember</Name>
              </Staff>";
}
```